# issues on xml file present in a set up project

Tags: xml, setup-project

I'm using an xml file to find whether the user is first time user or not for that i written the code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserFirstDetails>
<IsFirstTime>True</IsFirstTime>
<ProductOrderNum></ProductOrderNum>
<Drive></Drive>
</UserFirstDetails>
```

in form i written the code like this

```
string filePath1 = Application.StartupPath;
string org1 = filePath1 + "\\Input\\UserFirstDetails.xml";
UsrDetails.Load(org1);
XmlNode NdeFirst= UsrDetails.SelectSingleNode("UserFirstDetails/IsFirstTime");
FirstTime = NdeFirst.InnerText;
 if (FirstTime == "True")
 {
   NdeFirst.InnerText = "False";

   XmlNode productnum = UsrDetails.SelectSingleNode("UserFirstDetails/ProductOrderNum");
   productnum.InnerText = 1234567;

    XmlNode drivetag = UsrDetails.SelectSingleNode("UserFirstDetails/Drive");
    drive =C;

   FileInfo fp = new FileInfo(org1);
   fp.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;

   UsrDetails.Save(org1);
}
```

Its working fine for me when i installed the application for first time but when i did uninstall and again reinstall the application  i'm getting an xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserFirstDetails>
<IsFirstTime>False</IsFirstTime>
<ProductOrderNum>1234567</ProductOrderNum>
<Drive>C</Drive>
</UserFirstDetails>
```

instead of original

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <UserFirstDetails>
 <IsFirstTime>True</IsFirstTime>
 <ProductOrderNum></ProductOrderNum>
 <Drive></Drive>
 </UserFirstDetails>
```

Input folder properties are

```
 Always create-true
 condition -
 Transitive-False
```

Answer (score 0):

If that Xml file is in your setup and installed by the MSI file (in other words your app didn't create it) then the uninstall will uninstall it. Every file installed by the MSI setup will by default be uninstalled.

If you were to make a RemovePreviousVersions update (after incrementing setup project version) then the existing file would not be overwritten because overwrite rules include a "don't replace altered data files".

If you create the file in your app's code, then uninstall would not remove it.

I also recommend not using the Application.Startup path because that is typically the Program Files folder, and updating files there requires elevation. User's Application Data is a better location (after all, that's why it's called that) for data files.

For a single data item like that I'd probably use a HKCU registry entry. The issue with installing per-machine is that more than one user can run the app, so the first user that runs the app will mark every user as the first user, because another user who logs on will get the same Xml file as the first user.

Comment: Is it possible to change the files to be like original when we are unstalling the application

Comment: Thank you so much @PhilDW . I Got the correct output and i  used users application data  as that  you suggested  to me

Comment: again xml files are not deleting when i did uninstall my project now i'm using users application data folder only and i kept remove previous version property to true of setup project may i know what is the reason